# How to rewrite all underscores just in variables?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can you please help me how to rewrite all underscores just in variables?
For exmaple, I have url like this http://www.something.com/some/name_1.html, Viber chat add ?utm_source=Viber&utm_medium=Chat&utm_campaign=Private.

I need to rewrite with htaccess, underscores but only from variables, not from name_1.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Can you make it clearer that what your incoming input/URL should be looks like ?

Comment: I need to define in .htaccess, when somebody access  

http://www.something.com/some/name_1.html?utm_source=Viber&utm_medium=Chat&utm_campaign=Private

to send him to
http://www.something.com/some/name_1.html?utm-source=Viber&utm-medium=Chat&utm-campaign=Private